# Screen won't detach using ctrl+a d

Tags: ssh

I'm not sure if this is the right platform for this question, but if it's not, I'd be happy to post elsewhere.

I've ssh'd into a server to run some stuff in R, and now that it's running, I'm not able to detach the screen using "ctrl+a d". When I type ctrl+a d, I get either "^A d", or nothing.

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012530/screen-not-detaching-with-ctrla-d), which suggested that I open a second terminal window and remotely detach the screen, but when I typed in "screen -ls" I got back "No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-user", which is strange considering that a smaller version of this script ran perfectly/saved objects to Cyberduck as instructed, so I know my script is running.

For context, I'm running a Mac OSX, and the server I'm ssh'ing into is a linux.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Have you considered using `nohup` and running your program in the background?

Comment: Hey @Tarik! I hadn't head of `nohup` before, but after some quick googling, that seems like a good option! I found a [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/76875/how-to-run-script-via-ssh-that-doesnt-end-when-i-close-connection) that says I can use `ssh mySever 'nohup bash myscript.sh'`. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :-)

Comment: add the `&` to have it run on the background.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! :)